# Got System.InvalidOperationException in android

Tags: android

How to avoid

> You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it

exception in android ? App crashed initially after launched.

Comment: @Ranjit,  Are u used this line: Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

Comment: @RajSharma, I got solution and it works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Forms.Init() is called, the application throws this exception

> System.InvalidOperationException: You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init();

prior to
using it.

```
#Code Snippet

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App()); //  Exception happens here
}
```

[click here to detail](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26767)